Mirror image of entire document across the central horizontal line
I want to create a document which is printed twice. Once as a normal text starting from top and then also from the bottom as a mirror image.
Basically, it should look same after rotating 180 degree. It should also stop outputting anything on the page once it reaches the half way horizontal line. Anything extra should begin on a new page as if \newpage is invoked.
I tried looking at pgfmorepages and atbegshi packages but no avail.
I am not even sure how to begin. Are there any solutions?

You could start from the repeated 2-up layout from pgfmorepages and add a rotation:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a5paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\pgfmorepagesloadextralayouts

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{quack}%
{%
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}
  \def\pgfpageoptionbordercode{}
}%
{%
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
    physical pages=1,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
    current logical shipout=\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout%
  }
  \pgfpagessetdefaults
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    border code=\pgfpageoptionbordercode
  }
  \pgfpagesphysicalpage{1}{}
  \ifdim\paperheight>\paperwidth\relax
    % put side-by-side
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight},%
%    rotation=90,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight},%
    rotation=180,%
  }
  \else
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight},%
%    rotation=90,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight},%
    rotation=180,%
  }
  \fi
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{quack}

\begin{document}

\duckument

\end{document}



awesome. it does the job far better than i imagined.

@magguu You're welcome!
